# How to fix "Project Unavailable" error in DTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, envdte, visual-studio-sdk

I have a Visual Studio Template Wizard where eventually I need to conditionally (based in user selections) change the .NET target with:

> // project is of type EnvDTE.Project
>
> project.Properties.Item("TargetFrameworkMoniker").Value =
> ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"

The problem is that after this all references to project properties return "Project Unavailable".

After changing the .NET target I need to add some assemblies as references and without the project being available this no longer works.

Inverting the tasks order (first adding the references then changing the target) does not work, because I am adding some dependencies that require .NET 4.5 (and project is originally .NET 4.0).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is how I solved

> project.Properties.Item("TargetFrameworkMoniker").Value =
> ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5";
>
> project = (Project)((Array)(Dte.ActiveSolutionProjects)).GetValue(0);

The 2nd line gets a new copy of the Project using a previously initialized instance of Dte (this new project instances mirrors all the changes of the previous instance (even those not saved) so already has the target framework == 4.5 !!).

The new instance can be used to add project references, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for!